# PostgreSQL: store function in column as value

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql

Can functions be stored as anonymous functions directly in column as its value?

Let's say I want this function be stored in column.
Example (pseudocode):

Table my_table: pk (int), my_function (func)

func ( x ) { return x * 100 }

And later use it as:

```
select 
    t.my_function(some_input) AS output
from 
    my_table as t 
where t.pk = 1999
```

Function may vary for each pk.

Comment: Presumably you mean `my_function()` or `some_actual_schema.my_function()` instead of `t.my_function()`, since `t` is a table alias.  As long as we're not trying that bit of insanity, then as long as the function outputs a single non-set, non-record value (ie it doesn't output a row or a table), then yes, it should be fine.

Comment: No, it sounds like t.my_function() is EXACTLY what's he's asking for. Basically, the DB equivalent of a function pointer or clousure.

Comment: Yes, I meant something like closure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your title asks something else than your example.

1. A **function** has to be *created* before you can call it. (title)
2. An **expression** has to be evaluated. You would need a meta-function for that.  (example)

Here are solutions for both:

### 1. Evaluate expressions dynamically

You have to take into account that the resulting type can vary. I use polymorphic types for that.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1(int)
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT $1 * 100;';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f2(text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$$SELECT $1 || '_foo';$$;

CREATE TABLE my_expr (
  expr    text PRIMARY KEY
, def     text
, rettype regtype
);

INSERT INTO my_expr VALUES
  ('x', 'f1(3)'      , 'int')
, ('y', $$f2('bar')$$, 'text')
, ('z', 'now()'      , 'timestamptz')
;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_eval(text, _type anyelement = 'NULL'::text, OUT _result anyelement)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE
   'SELECT ' || (SELECT def FROM my_expr WHERE expr = $1)
   INTO _result;
END
$func$;
```

Related:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Call:

SQL is strictly typed, the same result column can only have *one* data type. For multiple rows with possibly heterogeneous data types, you might settle for type `text`, as every data type can be cast to and from `text`:

```
SELECT *, f_eval(expr) AS result  -- default to type text
FROM   my_expr;
```

Or return multplce columns like:

```sql
SELECT *
     , CASE WHEN rettype = 'text'::regtype        THEN f_eval(expr) END                    AS text_result  -- default to type text
     , CASE WHEN rettype = 'int'::regtype         THEN f_eval(expr, NULL::int) END         AS int_result
     , CASE WHEN rettype = 'timestamptz'::regtype THEN f_eval(expr, NULL::timestamptz) END AS tstz_result
  -- , more?
FROM   my_expr;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9d2d072bd3ab8ba44010fa8e095e2613)*

### 2. Create and use functions dynamically

It is possible to create functions dynamically and then use them. You cannot do that with plain SQL, however. You will have to use another [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) to do that or at least an [anonymous code block (DO statement)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html), introduced in PostgreSQL 9.0.

It can work like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_func (func text PRIMARY KEY, def text);

INSERT INTO my_func VALUES
  ('f'
 , $$CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f(int)
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT $1 * 100;'$$);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_create_func(text)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE (SELECT def FROM my_func WHERE func = $1);
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_create_func('f');
SELECT f(3);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9d2d072bd3ab8ba44010fa8e095e2613)*

You may want to drop the function afterwards.

In most cases you should just create the functions instead and be done with it. Use separate schemas if you have problems with multiple versions or privileges.

For more information on the features I used here, see [my related answer on dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7681/3684).

Comment: Thank you Erwin for this example. I suspected that what I'm asking might not work, so this or something like this, was plan B.

Comment: How are you assigning the return datatype in `x.f_eval`? I see you pass `_type anyelement` as the second argument; however, I don't see how it is being used in the function definition.

Comment: disregard the above comment... details found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557

Comment: I stumbled across this old answer and felt it was incomplete. You might still be interested in the update.