# Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I wrote a function that outputs a PostgreSQL `SELECT` query well formed in text form. Now I don't want to output a text anymore, but actually run the generated `SELECT` statement against the database and return the result - just like the query itself would.

#### What I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_of(integer)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   sensors varchar(100);   -- holds list of column names
   type    varchar(100);   -- holds name of table
   result  text;           -- holds SQL query
       -- declare more variables

BEGIN
      -- do some crazy stuff

      result := 'SELECT\r\nDatahora,' || sensors ||
      '\r\n\r\nFROM\r\n' || type ||
      '\r\n\r\nWHERE\r\id=' || $1 ||'\r\n\r\nORDER BY Datahora;';

      RETURN result;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
ALTER FUNCTION data_of(integer) OWNER TO postgres;
```

`sensors` holds the list of column names for the table `type`. Those are declared and filled in the course of the function. Eventually, they hold values like:

- `sensors`: `'column1, column2, column3'`
  Except for `Datahora` (`timestamp`) all columns are of type `double precision`.
- `type` :`'myTable'`
  Can be the name of one of four tables. Each has different columns, except for the common column `Datahora`.

[**Definition of the underlying tables**.](http://pastebin.com/A2tZ9K3Q)

The variable `sensors` will hold *all* columns displayed here for the corresponding table in `type`. For example: If `type` is `pcdmet` then `sensors` will be `'datahora,dirvento,precipitacao,pressaoatm,radsolacum,tempar,umidrel,velvento'`

The variables are used to build a `SELECT` statement that is stored in `result`. Like:

```
SELECT Datahora, column1, column2, column3
FROM   myTable
WHERE  id=20
ORDER  BY Datahora;
```

Right now, my function returns this statement as `text`. I copy-paste and execute it in pgAdmin or via psql. I want to automate this, run the query automatically and return the result. How can I do that?

Comment: I took the liberty to rewrite your question to clarify things - now that I think I understand, mostly. Feel free to roll back if you disagree.

Comment: Agreed :) Thank you for the improvement! I love how this community works

Answer (score 106, accepted):

### Dynamic SQL and `RETURN` type

<sup>(I saved the best for last, keep reading!)</sup>

You want to execute **dynamic SQL**. In principal, that's simple in PL/pgSQL with the help of [**`EXECUTE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). You don't need a cursor. In fact, most of the time you are better off without explicit cursors.

The problem you run into: you want to **return records of yet undefined type**. A function needs to declare its return type in the [**`RETURNS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) clause (or with `OUT` or `INOUT` parameters). In your case you would have to fall back to anonymous records, because *number*, *names* and *types* of returned columns vary. Like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION data_of(integer)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS ...
```

However, this is not particularly useful. You have to provide a column definition list with every call. Like:

```
SELECT * FROM data_of(17)
AS foo (colum_name1 integer
      , colum_name2 text
      , colum_name3 real);
```

But how would you even do this, when you don't know the columns beforehand?
You could use less structured document data types like `json`, `jsonb`, `hstore` or `xml`. See:

- [How to store a data table in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065244/how-to-store-a-data-table-or-listkeyvaluepairint-object-or-dictionary-in/27066058#27066058)

But, for the purpose of this question, let's assume you want to return individual, correctly typed and named columns as much as possible.

### Simple solution with fixed return type

The column `datahora` seems to be a given, I'll assume data type `timestamp` and that there are always two more columns with varying name and data type.

*Names* we'll abandon in favor of generic names in the return type.
*Types* we'll abandon, too, and cast all to `text` since *every* data type can be cast to `text`.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_of(_id integer)
  RETURNS TABLE (datahora timestamp, col2 text, col3 text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _sensors text := 'col1::text, col2::text';  -- cast each col to text
   _type    text := 'foo';
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
      SELECT datahora, ' || _sensors || '
      FROM   ' || quote_ident(_type) || '
      WHERE  id = $1
      ORDER  BY datahora'
   USING  _id;
END
$func$;
```

The variables `_sensors` and `_type` could be input parameters instead.

Note the [`RETURNS TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) clause.

Note the use of [`RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN54103). That is one of the more elegant ways to return rows from a dynamic query.

I use a name for the function parameter, just to make the `USING` clause of `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` less confusing. `$1` in the SQL-string does not refer to the function parameter but to the value passed with the `USING` clause. (Both happen to be `$1` in their respective scope in this simple example.)

Note the example value for `_sensors`: each column is cast to type `text`.

This kind of code is very vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection). I use [`quote_ident()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to protect against it. Lumping together a couple of column names in the variable `_sensors` prevents the use of `quote_ident()` (and is typically a bad idea!). Ensure that no bad stuff can be in there some other way, for instance by individually running the column names through `quote_ident()` instead. A `VARIADIC` parameter comes to mind ...

#### Simpler since PostgreSQL 9.1

With version 9.1 or later you can use [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to further simplify:

```sql
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('
   SELECT datahora, %s  -- identifier passed as unescaped string
   FROM   %I            -- assuming the name is provided by user
   WHERE  id = $1
   ORDER  BY datahora'
  ,_sensors, _type)
USING  _id;
```

Again, individual column names could be escaped properly and would be the clean way.

### Variable number of columns sharing the same type

After your question updates it looks like your return type has

- a variable *number* of columns
- but all columns of the same *type* `double precision` (alias `float8`)

Use an `ARRAY` type in this case to nest a variable number of values. Additionally, I return an array with column names:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_of(_id integer)
  RETURNS TABLE (datahora timestamp, names text[], values float8[])
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _sensors text := 'col1, col2, col3';  -- plain list of column names
   _type    text := 'foo';
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('
      SELECT datahora
           , string_to_array($1)  -- AS names
           , ARRAY[%s]            -- AS values
      FROM   %s
      WHERE  id = $2
      ORDER  BY datahora'
    , _sensors, _type)
   USING  _sensors, _id;
END
$func$;
```

## Various complete table types

To actually return **all columns of a table**, there is a simple, powerful solution using a [**polymorphic type**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_of(_tbl_type anyelement, _id int)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('
      SELECT *
      FROM   %s  -- pg_typeof returns regtype, quoted automatically
      WHERE  id = $1
      ORDER  BY datahora'
    , pg_typeof(_tbl_type))
   USING  _id;
END
$func$;
```

Call (important!):

```
SELECT * FROM data_of(NULL::pcdmet, 17);
```

Replace `pcdmet` in the call with any other table name.

#### How does this work?

`anyelement` is a pseudo data type, a polymorphic type, a placeholder for any non-array data type. All occurrences of `anyelement` in the function evaluate to the same type provided at run time. By supplying a value of a defined type as argument to the function, we implicitly define the return type.

PostgreSQL automatically defines a row type (a composite data type) for every table created, so there is a well defined type for every table. This includes temporary tables, which is convenient for ad-hoc use.

Any type can be `NULL`. Hand in a `NULL` value, cast to the table type: **`NULL::pcdmet`**.

Now the function returns a well-defined row type and we can use `SELECT * FROM data_of()` to decompose the row and get individual columns.

[**`pg_typeof(_tbl_type)`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) returns the name of the table as [object identifier type `regtype`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html). When automatically converted to `text`, identifiers are **automatically double-quoted and schema-qualified** if needed, defending against SQL injection automatically. This can even deal with schema-qualified table-names where `quote_ident()` would fail. See:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Comment: Thank you very much! All this help is priceless! And sure it solve the problem!

Comment: Great answer, but can't help feeling the first two solutions were just foreplay to the final very cool one ;-)

Comment: Can the final solution be wrapped in a function that takes the textual name of the relation as an argument? I've encountered this problem a few times where I have web applications with functions like `getData(String relationName, Int rowId)` and I'd like to implement by calling something like the above, but there's the danger of SQL Injection on `relationName`.

Comment: @beldaz: Please start a new question for this question. Comments are not the place. You can always add a link to this answer for context.

Comment: Is there a way to get the name of the table you pass to _tbl_type as a string?

Comment: @BrianPreslopsky: `pg_typeof(_tbl_type)::text`

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: Thank you.

Comment: `pg_typeof` seems does not work for TEMP TABLE. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: @EugenKonkov: `pg_typeof()` works for temporary tables just as well. (Temp tables are listed in system catalog tables just like regular table.) See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d5a557c6e0f06db1686dc4ff1cf85f33. Maybe you messed up your [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)? Or the syntax of the function call?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Yes, I did =(. Thank for hint. I miss `null::table_name` part

Comment: I know it's late but I can't seem to figure out how to pass in a string as the _tbl_type. I keep getting a syntax error at the call of data_of(5, NULL::'transactions'), which is at or near 'transactions'. Anyone know how to solve this? the function works great with using transactions instead of a string, but I can't call it with the table name. I posted a question about it here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65515168/pl-postgresql-how-to-convert-a-variable-into-a-table-name?noredirect=1#comment115830557_65515168)

Comment: @Jabi `data_of(5, NULL::transactions)` - no single quotes. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter is there a way to convert a string into the table name? the data is being passed from a Node server and so it's coming in as a string ('transactions') hence my issue- I've also looked into replacing the ' ' apostrophes but I couldn't find a way to do that outside of a function

Comment: @Jabinator1: You can produce the table name from a string inside the plpgsql function, **but** you can't get the dynamic return type this way, as this is determined by passing *in* the type. IOW: SQL forces you to declare the return type at call time at the latest.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Luckily I ended up figuring it out- Because I'm connecting to my server with MassiveJS I was able to do inline SQL in my server, which shortened it to one line of code! haha but thanks for the response!

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter.   first time see `NULL::pcdmet`. the manual too much `null`. Can you drop a manual reference link. Thanks.

Comment: How would one adapt the final answer to say pick a table dynamically? I.e. I have the table I need to reference 'aqe_idarea' in 2 different columns, how would I put it into the first argument of the function?

Comment: @Timothyjames67: Ask a new *question* with the necessary detail to make your case clear. You can always link to this one for context ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Sounds good thank you! I will write that up :)

Answer (score 4):

You'll probably want to return a [cursor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/plpgsql-cursors.html). Try something like this (I haven't tried it):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_of(integer)
  RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
      --Declaring variables
      ref refcursor;
BEGIN
      -- make sure `sensors`, `type`, $1 variable has valid value
      OPEN ref FOR 'SELECT Datahora,' || sensors ||
      ' FROM ' || type ||
      ' WHERE nomepcd=' || $1 ||' ORDER BY Datahora;';
      RETURN ref;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
ALTER FUNCTION data_of(integer) OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It returns a column named refcursor, and a line with "<unnamed portal XX>"! I'm not a PL/PgSQL's guru, but I'm not silly. It was my first attempt. BTW thanks for your try! :)

Comment: did you FETCH from the returned cursor? like `FETCH ref INTO target;` Cunsult the cursor docs for details on how to use a cursor. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/plpgsql-cursors.html

Comment: Amazing, very elegant and powerful approach. Works well with PgAdmin but NOT with PSQLODBC driver and ADODB.  In PgAdmin we have to add explicit  fetch all in <cursor_name> to get it working.

Comment: How would one use it? `FETCH data_of(1)`? I keep getting a syntax error there

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say but your question is very unclear. However below you'll find a self contained example how to create and use a function that returns a cursor variable. Hope it helps !

```
begin;

create table test (id serial, data1 text, data2 text);

insert into test(data1, data2) values('one', 'un');
insert into test(data1, data2) values('two', 'deux');
insert into test(data1, data2) values('three', 'trois');

create function generate_query(query_name refcursor, columns text[])
returns refcursor 
as $$
begin
  open query_name for execute 
    'select id, ' || array_to_string(columns, ',') || ' from test order by id';
  return query_name;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select generate_query('english', array['data1']);
fetch all in english;

select generate_query('french', array['data2']);
fetch all in french;
move absolute 0 from french; -- do it again !
fetch all in french;

select generate_query('all_langs', array['data1','data2']);
fetch all in all_langs;

-- this will raise in runtime as there is no data3 column in the test table
select generate_query('broken', array['data3']);

rollback;
```

Comment: instead of saying that is an unclear question, tell me what is missing, or what you want to know. I'm sorry for not being clear, although I tried so hard to make a good question. And I can improve it with your consideration.

Comment: @waldyr.ar: you updated version is now much better. It was simply unclear what you wanted to achieve and some details were missing (what are those _sensors_ and _type_ and how do they get their values). It's usually helps a lot if a question includes the simplest possible working code (i.e. that can be executed by the others) that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
# copy paste me into bash shell directly
clear; IFS='' read -r -d '' sql_code << 'EOF_SQL_CODE'
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_get_all_users_roles()
  -- define the return type of the result set as table
  -- those datatypes must match the ones in the src
  RETURNS TABLE (
                 id           bigint
               , email        varchar(200)
               , password     varchar(200)
               , roles        varchar(100)) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY 
   -- start the select clause
   SELECT users.id, users.email, users.password, roles.name as roles
   FROM user_roles
   LEFT JOIN roles ON (roles.guid = user_roles.roles_guid)
   LEFT JOIN users ON (users.guid = user_roles.users_guid)
   -- stop the select clause
;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
EOF_SQL_CODE
# create the function
psql -d db_name -c "$sql_code"; 

# call the function 
psql -d db_name -c "select * from func_get_all_users_roles() "
```

Comment: Wrong question?