# when should i use fetch keyword in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, cursor, plpgsql

I am new to pg cursor, I have a cursor here:

```
create function simplecur() returns refcursor as $$
declare 
    abc cursor for 
    select t.registrant, u.display_name from incident_info t, sys_user u
    where t.registrant != 10000000 and u.id = t.registrant
    group by t.registrant, u.display_name
    order by t.registrant ;
begin
    open abc;
    return abc;
end
$$language plpgsql;
```

I simply use

```
select simplecur()
```

it returns

```
abc
```

now, i want to know ,how could i get the result of my sql , when i use

```
fetch all from abc;
```

it show me like this:

```
ERROR:  cursor "abc" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have [an open transaction](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-USING) when you're using the cursor variable:

```
begin;
  select simplecur();
  fetch all in abc;
commit;
```

Another SO [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11747129/).