# How to create a record only if it doesn't exist, avoid duplications and don't raise any error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, transactions, rails-activerecord, upsert

It's well known that `Model.find_or_create_by(X)` actually does:

1. select by X
2. if nothing found -> create by X
3. return a record (found or created)

and there may be race condition between steps 1 and 2. To avoid a duplication of X in the database one should use an unique index on the set of fields of X. But if you apply an unique index then one of competing transactions would fail with exception (when trying to create a copy of X).

How can I implement 'a safe version' of `#find_or_create_by` which would never raise any exception and always work as expected?

Comment: How about using find_or_create_by: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-build-a-new-object ?

Comment: How it'll help to avoid problem with data duplication?

Comment: Well, unless I misunderstood the question, you can do something like `find_or_create_by_user_id_and_title(user.id, "My Uploads")` and this will return an existing record if there is one, or create a new one if there isn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is in the [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by)

> Whether that is a problem or not depends on the logic of the application, but in the particular case in which rows have a UNIQUE constraint an exception may be raised, just retry:
>
> ```
> begin
>   CreditAccount.find_or_create_by(user_id: user.id)
> rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
>   retry
> end
> ```

---

**Solution 1**

You could implement the following in your model(s), or in a Concern if you need to stay DRY

```
def self.find_or_create_by(*)
  super
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  retry
end
```

Usage: `Model.find_or_create_by(X)`

---

**Solution 2**

Or if you don't want to overwrite `find_or_create_by`, you can add the following to your model(s)

```
def self.safe_find_or_create_by(*args, &block)
  find_or_create_by *args, &block
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  retry
end
```

Usage: `Model.safe_find_or_create_by(X)`

Comment: Does this work if you're in a transaction block, e.g. within an `after_create` handler?

Answer (score 3):

It's the recurring problem of "SELECT-or-INSERT", closely related to the popular `UPSERT` problem. The upcoming [Postgres 9.5 supplies the new `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING | UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) to provide clean solutions for each.

#### Implementation for Postgres 9.4

For now, I suggest this bullet-proof implementation using two server-side plpgsql functions. Only the helper-function for the `INSERT` implements the more expensive error-trapping, and that's only called if the `SELECT` does not succeed.

This ***never*** raises an exception due to a unique violation and ***always*** returns a row.

Assumptions:

- Assuming a table named `tbl` with a column `x` of data type `text`. Adapt to your case accordingly.
- `x` is defined `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY`.
- You want to return the whole row from the underlying table (`return a record (found or created)`).
- In many cases the row is already there. (Does not have to be the majority of cases, `SELECT` is a lot cheaper than `INSERT`.) Else it may be more efficient to try the `INSERT` first.

Helper function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_insert_x(_x text)
  RETURNS SETOF tbl AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   INSERT INTO tbl(x) VALUES (_x) RETURNING *;

EXCEPTION WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN  -- catch exception, no row is returned
   -- do nothing
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Main function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_x(_x text)
  RETURNS SETOF tbl AS
$func$
BEGIN
   LOOP
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE x = _x
      UNION  ALL
      SELECT * FROM f_insert_x(_x)  -- only executed if x not found
      LIMIT  1;

      EXIT WHEN FOUND;       -- else keep looping
   END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_x('foo');
```

[**SQL Fiddle** demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7778a/1)

The function is based on what I have worked out in this related answer:

- **[Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)**

Detailed explanation and links there.

We *could* also create a generic function with polymorphic return type and dynamic SQL to work for any given column and table (but that's beyond the scope of this question):

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Basics for `UPSERT` in this related answer by Craig Ringer:

- [How to UPSERT (MERGE, INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE) in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-do-i-do-an-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)

Comment: This sounds similar to what the [upsert gem](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert) does.  It looks well-tested.  Can you recommend for/against just using it?  [P.S. thanks for the detailed explanation in any case!]

Comment: @Beni: I can't comment on the gem you mention, I don't know it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method called `find_or_create_by` in rails

This [link will help you to understand it better](http://maxivak.com/how-to-pass-multiple-attributes-to-find_or_create_by-in-rails-3-the-ruby-way/)

But personally I prefer to have a find first and if nothing found then create, (I think it has more control)

```
Ex:

user = User.find(params[:id])
#User.create(#attributes) unless user
```

HTH

Comment: Suppose you have two processes doing find_or_create in parallel: you'll get two separate records in DB... The question is how to avoid such situation?

Comment: same approach you could use with some locking which you can pass to active record , according to your requirements. read more here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#locking-records-for-update

Comment: Transactions was the first thing I think about. But seems like it's not the cure. It aims to lock existing records, not ones that just created in this or other transaction. Later I found solution with REPLACE statement for MySQL and INSERT trigger for PostgreSQL. I'd like to know is there other solutions