# how to return a table from function postgresql with multiples tables in the query?

Tags: function, postgresql, stored-procedures

i have a question, i have a query, that has a multiple tables and i want to create a function that return me that query as a table

```
SELECT mat.codigo as codmatr, mat.codigoalumno as codal, mat.codigoempresa as codemp ,mat.codigopresentacion as codpre,
    mat.codigosecretaria as codsec, mat.fecha as fechamat, mat.estado as estadomat,
    mat.vigencia as vigmat, p.apellidos as apeAl, p.apellidos||' '||p.nombres as nombrecompleto,
    p.nombres as nomAl,razonsocial ,pre.codigocurso as codcur,cur.nombre as curso
    FROM matricula mat join alumno al on mat.codigoalumno = al.codigoalumno
    join persona p on  al.codigoalumno = p.codigo
    join persona pe on mat.codigoalumno = pe.codigo
    left join empresa emp on mat.codigoempresa = emp.codigo
    join presentacion pre on mat.codigopresentacion = pre.codigo
    join curso cur on cur.codigo = pre.codigocurso
    order by nombrecompleto
```

thats is my query 
and this is my function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_lisMatricula() RETURNS SETOF Matricula AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r Matricula%rowtype;
r Persona%rowtype;

BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT mat.codigo as codmatr, mat.codigoalumno as codal, mat.codigoempresa as codemp ,mat.codigopresentacion as codpre,
    mat.codigosecretaria as codsec, mat.fecha as fechamat, mat.estado as estadomat,
    mat.vigencia as vigmat, p.apellidos as apeAl, p.apellidos||' '||p.nombres as nombrecompleto,
    p.nombres as nomAl,razonsocial ,pre.codigocurso as codcur,cur.nombre as curso
    FROM matricula mat join alumno al on mat.codigoalumno = al.codigoalumno
    join persona p on  al.codigoalumno = p.codigo
    join persona pe on mat.codigoalumno = pe.codigo
    left join empresa emp on mat.codigoempresa = emp.codigo
    join presentacion pre on mat.codigopresentacion = pre.codigo
    join curso cur on cur.codigo = pre.codigocurso
    order by nombrecompleto
    LOOP       
        RETURN NEXT r;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

select * from fn_lisMatricula()
```

the problem is the result of the function only has the structure of my "matricula" table but i want the structure of all my query result.

Comment: Have you tried creating a view with that, and then using the view intead?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot make sense of your question. Maybe you are looking for [something like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)?

Comment: i want to return a table with the columns of my query, that query has more than 2 tables how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `RETURNS TABLE` and specify the result column types and names. See [the PostgreSQL documentation for PL/PgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) and [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html).

Alternately, you can:

- `CREATE TYPE` a custom composite type for the purpose and return a `SETOF` it;
- Use `OUT` parameters and `RETURNS SETOF RECORD`,
- Use `RETURNS SETOF RECORD` and specify the result record structure when invoking the function

`RETURNS TABLE(...)` is by far the simplest option of these.

Comment: yeah i read somethig about returns table but i dont know how its works , i type some code to return table but doesnt works, can you write me a example code to return table? an easy one please . Thanks =)

Comment: @J.A. No, I won't write an example. You can already find many examples here on Stack Overflow, in the PostgreSQL documentation, and elsewhere. Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/search and here: http://google.com/