# postgresql: select non-outliers from view

Tags: sql, postgresql, outliers, postgresql-8.3

Using version 8.3 (no choice in the matter).

I cannot use ";WITH x AS" style queries because that is not supported (from what I can tell in 8.3.  I have attempted to use them and they are not recognized).  I can also not use TOP of course since I'm not in SQL Server.  I tried to use the following limit query but was stymied by the following error:

```
SELECT * FROM myView LIMIT(SELECT (COUNT(int_field) * 0.95)::integer FROM myView);

ERROR:  argument of LIMIT must not contain subqueries
```

It's not ideal since it doesn't remove the lower 5% but I can live just the highest 5% being removed.

Comment: You havent' really explained what you expected from this query. Is it 95% of the rows? If so, according to what ordering expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Postgres 8.4 there is no built-in way to get a percentage of rows with a single query. Consider [this closely related thread on the pgsql-sql list](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/162867790911181130n74be837eo29e3c408724c88f7@mail.gmail.com#162867790911181130n74be837eo29e3c408724c88f7@mail.gmail.com)

You could write a function doing the work in a single call. this should work in **Postgres 8.3**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(_pct int)
  RETURNS SETOF v_t AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _ct     int := (SELECT count(*) FROM v_t);
   _offset int := (_ct * $1) / 100;
   _limit  int := (_ct * (100 - 2 * $1)) / 100;
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY
SELECT *
FROM   v_t
OFFSET _offset
LIMIT  _limit;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM foo(5)
```

This actually crops 5% from top *and* bottom.

The return type `RETURNS SETOF v_t` is derived from a view named `v_t` directly.

[-> **SQLfiddle** for Postgres 8.3.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!10/6e6f4/1)

Comment: Tried to create this function and got the following error:ERROR:  language "plpgsql" does not exist
HINT:  Use CREATE LANGUAGE to load the language into the database.

Comment: Sorry I created this language.  I thought I might not have the rights to do so.   But now I'm getting "type "v_t" does not exist".

Comment: @lostinthebits: Replace all occurrences of `v_t` with the actual name of your view or table. This could be made [generic with a polymorphic type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557), but Postgres 8.3 is just too outdated and does not have [`pg_typeof()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE). So the function works only for one object.