# How to return uncertain number columns of a table from a postgresql function?

Tags: postgresql, types, plpgsql

As we know, plpgsql functions can return a table like this:

```
RETURNS table(int, char(1), ...)
```

But how to write this function, when the list of columns is uncertain at the time of creating the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a function returns anonymous records

```
RETURNS SETOF record
```

you **have to** provide a column definition list when calling it with `SELECT * FROM`. SQL demands to know column names and types to interpret **`*`**. For registered tables and types this is provided by the system catalog. For functions you need to declare it yourself *one way or the other*. Either in the function definition or in the call. The call could look like [@Craig already provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21105124/939860). You probably didn't read his answer carefully enough.

Depending on what you need exactly, there are **a number of ways around this**, though:

### 1) Return a single anonymous record

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc_single()  -- return a single anon rec
  RETURNS record AS
$func$
DECLARE
   rec record;
BEGIN
   SELECT into rec  1, 'foo';  -- note missing type for 'foo'
   RETURN rec;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is a very limited niche. Only works for a single anonymous record from a function defined with:

```
RETURNS record
```

Call without `* FROM`:

```
SELECT myfunc_single();
```

Won't work for a SRF (set-returning function) and only returns a string representation of the whole record (type `record`). Rarely useful.
To get individual cols from a single anonymous record, you need to provide a column definition list again:

```
SELECT * FROM myfunc_single() AS (id int, txt unknown); -- note "unknown" type
```

### 2) Return well known row type with a super-set of columns

Example:

```
CREATE  TABLE t (id int, txt text, the_date date);
INSERT INTO t VALUES  (3, 'foz', '2014-01-13'), (4, 'baz', '2014-01-14');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc_tbl()  -- return well known table
  RETURNS SETOF t AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   TABLE t;
   -- SELECT * FROM t;  -- equivalent
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The function returns *all* columns of the table. This is short and simple and performance won't suffer as long as your table doesn't hold a huge number of columns or huge columns.

Select individual columns on call:

```
SELECT id, txt FROM myfunc_tbl();
SELECT id, the_date FROM myfunc_tbl();
```

[**-> SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/edbb9/1) demonstrating all.

### 3) Advanced solutions

This answer is long enough already. And this closely related answer has it all:
[Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Look to the last chapter in particular: **Various complete table types**

Answer (score 1):

If the result is of uncertain/undefined format you must use `RETURNS record` or (for a multi-row result) `RETURNS SETOF record`.

The calling function must then specify the table format, eg:

```
SELECT my_func() AS result(a integer, b char(1));
```

BTW, `char` is an awful data type with insane space-padding rules that date back to the days of fixed-width file formats. Don't use it. Always just use `text` or `varchar`.

Given comments, let's make this really explicit:

```
regress=> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_something() RETURNS SETOF record AS $$
SELECT 1, 2, TEXT 'a';
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
CREATE FUNCTION

regress=> SELECT * FROM f_something();
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM f_something();

regress=> SELECT * FROM f_something() AS x(a integer, b integer, c text);
 a | b | c 
---+---+---
 1 | 2 | a
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your reply. I'll appreciate if you can give me an example code?

Comment: I have tried using returns record, but the error occurs like this: ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"

Comment: @Moon_of_father Did you read the 2nd half of my answer? (Edit) Updated with step-by-step example.