# PostgreSQL: How to display only selected columns of a single table within CASE expression in function?

Tags: postgresql, case, plpgsql

Example: I am passing two parameters to function namely n(case number) and tname(table name), and want to display rows accordingly.

--Table "testing"

```
create table testing
(
  rollno integer,
  fname text,
  lname text,
  age integer,
  branch text,
  phno integer,
  email text,
  address text,
  city text,
  state text,
  country text
)
```

--Rows insertion

```
insert into testing values(1,'aaa','bbb',25,'CS',1234567890,'abc@gmail.com','sector1','xyz','zyx','yxz');

insert into testing values(2,'zzz','xxx',25,'EE',987654321,'zzz@gmail.com','sector2','uvw','wvu','vuw');
```

--Function "f1()"

```
create or replace function f1(n integer,tname varchar)/*n for case number and tname for table name */
returns setof tname as 
$body$
begin
     case n
     when 1 then
     return query execute format ($$ select rollno,fname from %I $$,tname);

     when 2 then 
     return query execute format ($$ select lname,age,branch from %I $$,tname);

     when 3 then
     return query execute format ($$ select phno,email,address,city,country from %I $$,tname);

     end case;
end
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

--Function calling

```
select * from f1(1,'testing');
/*Show only case "1" select query result*/

select * from f1(2,'testing');
/*Show only case "2" select query result*/

select * from f1(3,'testing');
/*Show only case "3" select query result*/
```

Comment: Function return types cannot be dynamic based on a parameter. You'd have to use `RETURNS SETOF RECORD` - in which case the caller has to specify the expected data type(s).

Comment: @Craig Ringer, So which block of code do i specify the columns definitions?

Comment: the caller of the function. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html, search for "column definition list".

Comment: @Craig Ringer, Thank you so much for providing link.

Comment: @Craig Ringer, Yup! Finally i got it, Thank You so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [Craig is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779074/postgresql-how-to-display-only-selected-columns-of-a-single-table-within-case-e#comment34729915_22779074) that return types cannot be dynamic in function declarations, there ***is*** a way around this with [**polymorphic types**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC). This is surprisingly simple and would actually work flawlessly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_of(_tbl_type anyelement)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS
$func$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM '|| pg_typeof(_tbl_type);
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call (important!):

```
SELECT rollno,fname FROM data_of(NULL::testing);
SELECT * FROM data_of(NULL::my_schema.my_table);
SELECT * FROM data_of(NULL::my_custom_type);
```

What you need is a well-known type. For every table there is a well-known type automatically. But you can create *any* type, cast `NULL` to it and pass it to the function. This way you can build exactly what you have in your question ...

Related answer with **a lot more details**:
[Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)