# PostgreSQL: Structure of query does not match function result type using polymorphic type "anyelement"

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, polymorphism

Problem: Getting error while returning the selected rows from table using polymorphic type "anyelement".

Error: structure of query does not match function result type.

---Table

```
CREATE TABLE tes1
(
    rollno integer,
    fname text,
    lname text,
    age integer,
    branch text,
    phno integer,
    email text,
    address text,
    city text,
    state text,
    country text
)
```

---Function

```
create or replace function fun_test(column_name varchar,relation_name anyelement)
returns setof anyelement as
$body$
declare
        str varchar;
        grouping varchar;
        additional_column varchar;
        select_query varchar;
begin
       if column_name='fname' then
               str:=quote_ident(column_name);
               additional_column:=' max("address") as addr, max("city") as cty, max("state") as st, max("country") as cntry';
           grouping:='"rollno"'||','||quote_ident(column_name);
   else
           str:=quote_ident(column_name);
           additional_column:=' max("address") as addr, max("city") as cty, max("state") as st, max("country") as cntry';
           grouping:='"rollno"'||','||quote_ident(column_name);
   end if;

   select_query:= 'select rollno,'||str||','||additional_column||' from '||pg_typeof(relation_name)||
   ' group by '|| grouping;

   raise info '%',select_query;

   return query execute select_query;
end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

---Calling function

```
 select * from fun_test('fname',NULL::test)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a simple typo?

```
CREATE TABLE tes1
...

select * from fun_test('fname',NULL::test)
```

As for the follow up in the comment

> Error DETAIL: Returned type text does not match expected type integer in column 4

The error message is pretty obvious. You need to cast the 4th value in your `SELECT` statement to `integer` or use `text` in the type definition. In your current function there are more mismatches between defined type and what you return.

Comment: test instead of tes1 is typing error. But error remains same.

Comment: Error DETAIL:  Returned type text does not match expected type integer in column 4.

Comment: Oh! I got it. So i need to give all columns, It's not possible for displaying required columns?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it seems that as you return more than one column, so the return type should be set of record.

```
 create or replace function fun_test(column_name varchar,relation_name anyelement)
 returns setof record as
 ...
```

Comment: [Explanation in the last chapter here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Comment: @INait, Yup! I tried that also. But not getting expected solution.

Comment: @INait, I want to call function without column definition list like as shown above in example.