# PostgreSQL functions: return setof tablename as variable

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remote (_table_name text)
  RETURNS SETOF my_table AS
$func$
DECLARE
   sql text := format('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id = 1', _table_name);
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql
   USING _table_name;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select * from remote('my_table')
```

But I would like to have a dynamic `RETURNS SETOF _table_name`.

I get this error if I do so:

```
ERROR:  type "_table_name" does not exist
```

How can I achieve that?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer here: [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_remote(_table_name anyelement)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS
$func$
DECLARE
   sql text := format('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id = 1', pg_typeof(_table_name));
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql
   USING _table_name;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select * from get_remote(NULL::my_table)
```

That was a tricky one though ...