# SQL Injection-safe call of polymorphic function

Tags: database, postgresql, sql-injection, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Several times I've found myself refactoring web application code and end up wanting to do something like this (Groovy in this case, but could be anything):

```
Map getData(String relationName, Integer rowId) {
    def sql = Sql.newInstance([...])
    def result = sql.firstRow('SELECT getRelationRow(?,?)', relationName, rowId)
    sql.close()
    return new HashMap(result)
}
```

where the stored procedure `getRelationRow(relname text, rowid integer)` executes dynamic sql to retrieve the row of the specified `rowid` in the requested relation. The best example I've seen of such a function is [this polymorphic function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751557/290182) using `anyelement` type, and is called as

```
SELECT * FROM data_of(NULL::pcdmet, 17);
```

However to call this in the above code would require

```
def result = sql.firstRow("SELECT * FROM data_of(NULL::${relationName},?)",  rowId)
```

that is, it required the relation name to be pasted into the query, which risks SQL Injection. So is there away to keep the polymorphic goodness of the stored procedure but allow it to be called with generic relation names?

Comment: Very interesting indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done this way. I assume Groovy is using *prepared statements* here, which requires that input and return types are known at prepare time, while my function derives the return type from the polymorphic input type.

I am pretty sure you need string concatenation. But don't fret, there are functions like `pg_escape()` to sanitize table names and make SQLi impossible. Don't know Groovy, but it should have that, too.

#### Or does it?

Based on the function `data_of(..)` at the end of this related answer:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

With [`PREPARE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-prepare.html) I can make this work by declaring the return type explicitly:

```
PREPARE fooplan ("relationName") AS  -- table name works as row type
SELECT * FROM data_of($1, $2);
```

Then I can hand in `NULL`, which is cast to `"relationName"` from the prepared context:

```
EXECUTE fooplan(NULL, 1);
```

So this might work after all, if your interface supports this. But you still have to concatenate the table name as return data type (and therefore defend against SQLi). Catch 22 I guess.

Comment: Ah well, figured you'd know if anyone did. I always feel a bit dubious of escaping strings, but yes that's probably the way to go. So far I've resorted to JSON to have a constant return type.

Comment: @beldaz: I am only half an expert here, since I don't know Groovy. But if it's prepared statements, then I am afraid you have to concatenate one way or the other. I added another idea.

Comment: Yes it's prepared statements, more to dissociate the parameters from the query than for any other benefits. Interesting idea about using `PREPARE`. Not sure I have access to it in the languages I typically use (Groovy/JDBC, Java/JDBC or PHP/PDO) but worth a look.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - I've posted a question as a follow-up at https://stackoverflow.com/q/75487149/584940.  I'm curious on what your thoughts might be.