# Function returning varius table types. pl/pgsql

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Is it possible to create a function in PostgreSQL with varying return type?
Example: Create function that gets data from table given as a argument and return it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION data_picker(tablename varchar) AS
$$ SELECT * FROM $1 $$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: You can define it as `returns record` but then you need to specify the structure of the result each time you _call_ the function: `select * from data_picker('foobar') as foobar (x integer, y varchar)` (Btw: `select * from $1` won't work in the first place. You will need dynamic SQL and a PL/pgSQL function for that)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only hack it by creating procedure, that will `create table as select * from table_name_in_function_argument` when you run it. so it looks like  `select * from data_picker(table_name_in_function_argument); SELECT * from table_name_in_function_argument` in separate statement...

Comment: Hmm, but what do You think about turning this data into json format ( i must do it anyway ). Maybe this is the answer?

Comment: yes, you can return json. but won't be your question :) return type will remain the same - one json value

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but probably it is not what you want :(. PostgreSQL is based on static type system - and result of any function must be known before execution, so although you can write function that can returns different data, you have to specify expected result in calling SELECT.

you can write function like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dont_do_it(tablename text)
RETURNS SETOF record AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %I', tablename);
RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But simple usage fails:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM  dont_do_it('oo');
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM  dont_do_it('oo');
                       ^
```

You have to specify expected result:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM  dont_do_it('oo') AS (a int);
┌────┐
│ a  │
╞════╡
│ 10 │
└────┘
(1 row)
```

Based on my experience - functions that can returns different structures are bad idea. It is partial implementation of procedures and `CALL` statement, but Postgres has not it, so the implementation of this patttern in Postgres is unsupported and should be prohibited (or emulated via cursors).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fetcher(c refcursor, tablename text)
RETURNS refcursor AS $$
BEGIN
  OPEN c FOR EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %I', tablename);
  RETURN c;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

postgres=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
postgres=# SELECT fetcher('c1', 'oo');
┌─────────┐
│ fetcher │
╞═════════╡
│ c1      │
└─────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# FETCH ALL FROM c1;
┌────┐
│ a  │
╞════╡
│ 10 │
└────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# COMMIT;
COMMIT
```

Comment: For the price of *two* round trips to the db server, one might as well return the text of the generated query and execute that in the second call. What's the benefit of a cursor? The simple case in the question can be solved with a polymorphic parameter and a single call.

Comment: When you use a returning polymorphic types, then you have knowledge about returned result before execution. Semantically it is only different syntax of RETURNS [SETOF] RECORD. On second hand - cursors can be used everywhere - although the set of use cases is limited (it is hard to use REFCURSOR function deeper inside other query) -  The cost of cursors is less than small - FETCH is pretty fast command (no planner cost, minimal parser cost), and it returns block of rows in one round.

Comment: The OP demonstrates an example where he passes a table name to the function. So he has knowledge about the return type at *function call time*, which can be solved with a polymorphic function parameter & return type as you doubtless know. I posted [sample code under the duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries) - last paragraph "Various complete table types".