# A PL/pgSQL function with varying return type (and varying inner query)

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

## The data

Suppose I have the following data:

```
create temp table my_data1 (
  id serial, val text
);

create temp table my_data2 (
  id serial, val int
);

insert into my_data1(id, val)
values (default, 'a'), (default, 'c'), (default, 'd'), (default, 'b');

insert into my_data2(id, val)
values (default, 1), (default, 3), (default, 4), (default, 2);
```

## The problem

I would like to write a `plpgsql` function which has 2 arguments: *tbl* (taking values `my_data1` or `my_data2`) and *order_by* (which can be `id` or `val` or null). The function should fetch all rows from the table specified in *tbl* and order them by the column specified in *order_by*.

Below there are 2 solutions I have found (see also [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/11939/2)). **The question is which of them is preferable, and if there exists an even better solution.**

## Solution using temp table

I came up with the following workaround:

```
create function my_work(tbl text, order_by text default null)
returns text as
$my_work$
declare
  q text;
begin
  q := 'select * from ' || quote_ident(tbl);
  if order_by is not null then
    q := q || ' order by ' || quote_ident(order_by);
  end if;
  return q;
end
$my_work$ language plpgsql;

create function my_fetch(_query text, into_table text)
returns void as
$my_fetch$
begin
  execute format($$
    create temp table %I
    on commit drop
    as %s
  $$, quote_ident(into_table), _query);
end
$my_fetch$ language plpgsql;
```

Then it remains to execute the following lines (preferably surrounded with 'begin/commit'):

```
select my_fetch(my_work('my_data1','id'), 'my_tmp');
select * from my_tmp;
```

Are there any negative side effects in this solution, e.g. is creating a temp table costy?

## Another solution (using pg_typeof)

I've also read a great [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557) on various approaches to dynamic queries with varying results. From the options mentioned there it seems the following is the best solution for my situation:

```
create or replace function not_my_work(_tbl_type anyelement, order_by text default null)
returns setof anyelement as
$func$
declare
  q text;
begin
   q := format('
    select *
    from   %s
  ', pg_typeof(_tbl_type));
  if order_by is not null then
    q := q || ' order by ' || quote_ident(order_by);
  end if;
  return query execute q;
end
$func$ language plpgsql;

select not_my_work(null::my_data1, 'id');
```

Does this approach have any advantages over the approach using temp table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two comments to the first solution.

First, use or `%I` or `quote_ident()` in `format()` function, not both. Compare:

```
with q(s) as (
    values ('abba'), ('ABBA')
    )
select 
    quote_ident(s) ok1, 
    format('%I', s) ok2, 
    format('%I', quote_ident(s)) bad_idea
from q;

  ok1   |  ok2   |  bad_idea  
--------+--------+------------
 abba   | abba   | abba
 "ABBA" | "ABBA" | """ABBA"""
(2 rows)
```

Second, you do not need two functions:

```
create or replace function my_select(into_table text, tbl text, order_by text default null)
returns void as $function$
declare
    q text;
begin
    q := 'select * from ' || quote_ident(tbl);
    if order_by is not null then
        q := q || ' order by ' || order_by;
    end if;
    execute format($$
        create temp table %I
        on commit drop
        as %s
    $$, into_table, q);
end
$function$ language plpgsql;

begin;
select my_select('my_tmp', 'my_data1', 'id');
select * from my_tmp;
commit;

BEGIN
 my_select 
-----------

(1 row)

 id | val 
----+-----
  1 | a
  2 | c
  3 | d
  4 | b
(4 rows)

COMMIT
```

In this particular case, the second solution is better. 
A temporary table is not particularly expensive, but still unnecessary.
The cost will be the more important the more data in the table.
If you have a good alternative to create a temporary table, use it.
Besides, the need to include the function call and the select query in a transaction can be a bit cumbersome in some cases.

The second solution is smart and is ideally suited to the task at hand.

Comment: Thanks for the observation concerning format - initially I wrote that statement using quote_ident, and then rewrote using format, forgetting to remove quote_ident.

Do I get correctly that, if I had a lot of data, temp table would be considerably more expensive than an explicit select? Is it because in case of temp table some records would be fetched to disc, while in the case of select not?

Comment: The data is always copied to a temporary table, this is the additional cost that does not exist in the second solution. In case of small amount of data the difference may be insignificant.