# How to derive a column name in the return type from input parameters to the function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

Using Postgres 9.5 I have built this function:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION func_getratio_laglag(_numeratorLAG text, _n1 int, _denominatorLAG text, _n2 int, _table text)
    RETURNS TABLE (date_t timestamp without time zone, customer_code text, index text, ratio real) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
 RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
        'SELECT 
    date_t,
    customer_code,
    index,
        (LAG('||quote_ident(_numeratorLAG)||',' || quote_literal(_n1)||') OVER W / LAG('||quote_ident(_denominatorLAG)||','|| quote_literal(_n2)||') OVER W) '
         || ' FROM ' || quote_ident(_table) 
         || ' WINDOW W AS (PARTITION BY customer_code ORDER BY date_t asc);';
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

All the function does is allow me the ability to pick a 2 different columns from a specified table and calculate a ratio between them based on different lag windows. To execute the function above I use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM func_getratio_laglag('order_first',1,'order_last',0,'customers_hist');
```

This returns a table with the column labels `date_t`, `customer_code`, `index` and `ratio`. I have really struggled on how to output ratio as a dynamic column label. That is, I would like to make it contingent on the input parameters e.g. if I ran the select query above then I would like the column labels `date_t`, `customer_code`, `index` and **`order_first_1_order_last_0`**.

I am stuck, any advice or hints?

Comment: Your text says Postgres 9.5, I took the liberty to adjust the tag accordingly.

Comment: Thankyou for assistance Erwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to derive a column name in the return type from input parameters to the function?

The short answer: **Not possible.**
SQL is very rigid about column data types and names. Those have to be declared before or at call time at the latest. No exceptions. No truly dynamic column names.

I can think of 3 half-way workarounds:

#### 1. Column aliases

Use your function as is (or rather the audited version I suggest below) and add column aliases in the function call:

```
SELECT * FROM func_getratio_laglag('order_first',1,'order_last',0,'customers_hist')
AS f(date_t, customer_code, index, order_first_1_order_last_0)
```

I would do that.

#### 2. Column definition list

Create your function to return anonymous records:

```
RETURNS SETOF record
```

Then you have to provide a column definition list with every call:

```
SELECT * FROM func_getratio_laglag('order_first',1,'order_last',0,'customers_hist')
AS f(date_t timestamp, customer_code text, index text, order_first_1_order_last_0 real)
```

I would ***not*** do that.

#### 3. Use a registered row type as polymorphic input / output type.

Mostly useful if you happen to have row types at hand. You *could* register a row type on the fly by crating a temporary table, but that seems like ***overkill for your use case***.

Details in the last chapter of this answer:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

### Function audit

Use [**`format()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to make building query string much more safe and simple.
[Read the manual if you are not familiar with it](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_getratio_laglag(
                           _numerator_lag   text, _n1 int
                         , _denominator_lag text, _n2 int
                         , _table regclass)
   RETURNS TABLE (date_t timestamp, customer_code text, index text, ratio real) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format (
     'SELECT date_t, customer_code, index
           , (lag(%I, %s) OVER w / lag(%I, %s) OVER w)  -- data type must match
      FROM   %s 
      WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY customer_code ORDER BY date_t)'
    , _numerator_lag, _n1, _denominator_lag, _n2, _table::text
   );
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note the data type `regclass` for the table name. That's my personal (optional) suggestion.

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Aside: I would also advise not to use mixed-case identifiers in Postgres.

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: Thankyou for the detail. Just to reiterate, there is no solution for what I seek and the workarounds you suggest (notably point 1) is simply to rename the columns which still needs to be done manually  if I decided to change any of the inputs. Might need to look into an alternative solution, like feeding this into a python dataframe.

Comment: @RRoszko: Yes. But when you think about it: you are providing column names as function parameters anyway. What keeps you from also providing a derived column alias?

Comment: I originally envisaged to use loops so I could feed arguments into my lag calculations, e.g. 0, 1, 2 etc. To be honest I didn't think about it too in depth at the moment and it serves more as an ad-hoc calculation.