# Add a column to a record variable of %rowtype

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, types, plpgsql

I have a plpgsql function in PostgreSQL 9.2.9 that needs to return multiple columns. Most of the columns come out of a single table, so I have declared the virtual table (is that term correct?) `rc` as:

```
rc "Sequence"%rowtype;
```

This works perfectly, except I have an additional 2 columns to add to the returned data. The function works correctly if I replace the above declaration with:

```
 rc RECORD;
```

along with a few other minor code changes. But then I need to always expressly call the function with a very long `SELECT` command that incorporates all the column definitions.

How do I get the best of both worlds, i.e. return all columns for `"Sequence"` table and add 2 new columns (`"AverageSED"` and `"avDailySED"`) with a simple:

```
SELECT * FROM production1('2016-02-27 00:00:00','2016-03-11 00:00:00');
```

This is my general function as an example (cut down for easier reading) that uses RECORD type.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION production1(tme1 timestamp without time zone, tme2 timestamp without time zone, mn integer)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
 -- Could possibly use (CREATE TYPE rcholder %rowtype) and use a function with a sub-function that then takes the rc RECORD and recasts it to type %rowtype. This would mean the column descriptor in the SELECT call could be dropped
  rc record;
  AverageSED Real;
  avDailySED Real;

BEGIN
-- Calculate average of value from Log_Alpha table
SELECT AVG("logSED")::Real
    FROM "Log_Alpha"
    WHERE "logTime" >= tme1 AND "logTime" < tme2
    INTO averageSED;

-- Select the required row from the sequence data table
  FOR rc IN
    SELECT *, AverageSED, avDailySED
    FROM "Sequence"
    WHERE "Sequence"."seqMinute" = mn AND "Sequence"."seqTime" >= tmeA AND "Sequence"."seqTime" <= tmeB
    ORDER BY "Sequence"."seqTime"
  LOOP
    rc."seqTime" = rc."seqTime" - '1 day'::interval;

  -- Use a subquery to calculate the average SED for all data for the day pertaining to this record date field
    SELECT AVG("logSED")::Real into rc.avDailySED FROM "Log_Alpha"
    WHERE "Log_Alpha"."logTime" >= rc."seqTime" and "Log_Alpha"."logTime" < (rc."seqTime" + '1 day'::interval);

    RETURN NEXT rc ;-- (AverageSED,avDailySED);
  END LOOP;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As such, this function needs a very long `SELECT` query in excess of 1400 characters long due to all the columns available in the `"Sequence"` table.

Comment: It's unclear whether you want to shorten the `RETURNS` clause of the function definition or some SQL commands in the function body - or both? It would be very helpful to provide a minimal example of the complete function you work with (even if it's not working, yet)

Comment: I've amended the question with my abbreviated function. Hope that helps. What I'm trying to do is reduce the SELECT query to that seen in my question, as opposed to having a very, very long query. The SELECT query ultimately gets nested in Delphi for FastReport reporting purposes, and is cumbersome to maintain. I don't really mind if this results in a very long RETURNS clause at all, though avoiding both would be ideal.

Comment: `tmeA`, `tmeB` or `tme1`, `tme2`? Please make the function consistent. And :Postgres 9.2.9? [Urgently consider upgrading](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) at least to the latest minor release.

Comment: It seems like your problem is *not* the variable definition (the `record` variable works just fine), but the return type (`RETURNS` clause) of the function. Your question is a bit misleading there - or this is the basic misunderstanding.

Comment: Either type records or %rowtype work for me, however I have been unsuccessful in finding a way to add additional columns to a %rowtype "vitual table" if that makes sense. If by anonymous you mean I have no column names or data types per column, well I think that is effectively what I am trying to overcome with the RECORD type, as I have to keep defining it in the query of the function. ie SELECT * FROM production1('2016-02-27 00:00:00','2016-03-11 00:00:00') AS table(col1 Integer, col2 Integer, col3 Real...etc.);

Comment: Consider this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557 and [this manual page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS). Should help to clear some confusion.

Comment: Yes, to confirm, I can successfully make the function work by either returning a setof RECORDS or a setof %ROWTYPE. However with %ROWTYPE I cannot see a means of adding the two extra columns (AverageSED,avDailySED) so I opted to use RECORDS, where I have been successful in adding the extra columns. Records however are anonymous by nature, unlike %rowtype. I need the best of both :)

Comment: Sorry, this has been going on for some days so my strategy has changed somewhat. As I could not find a means of adding columns to a setof %rowtype, I opted instead to tackle the setof record hurdle, which is to eliminate the need for a lengthy select query to the function. The original question is therefore somewhat misleading (unless you have an answer for how to add columns to %rowtype too... :) I have read the manual page before that you referenced, but not the stackoverflow question. Will take a look shortly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the return type of the function, ***not*** the variable `rc` inside the function, which works just fine.

You can either create another type to use in a `RETURNS SETOF <row_type>`, [like @Pavel demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42967756/939860). (But don't use inheritance here, that's an academic aside, like Pavel already mentioned.)

***Or*** you can use [`RETURNS TABLE ()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) instead. (That's what I would do.)

Also, your whole function can be radically simplified to a single SQL query with a `LATERAL` subquery (requires **Postgres 9.3+**, consider upgrading to a current version!):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION production1(tme1 timestamp, tme2 timestamp, mn int)
  RETURNS TABLE ( -- list all columns of "Sequence" here! Plus ...
                , average_sed  real
                , av_daily_sed real) AS
$func$
   SELECT s.*, a1.average_sed, a2.av_daily_sed
   FROM   "Sequence" s
   CROSS JOIN (  -- safe for an aggregate that always returns a row
      SELECT AVG("logSED")::real AS average_sed
      FROM   "Log_Alpha"
      WHERE  "logTime" >= tme1
      AND    "logTime" <  tme2
      ) a1
   LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT AVG("logSED")::real AS av_daily_sed
      FROM   "Log_Alpha" a
      WHERE  a."logTime" >= (s."seqTime" - interval '1 day')
      and    a."logTime" <   s."seqTime" 
      ) a2 ON TRUE
   WHERE  s."seqMinute" = mn
   AND    s."seqTime" >= tme1
   AND    s."seqTime" <  tme2  -- I assume you want '<' like above
   ORDER  BY s."seqTime";
$func$  LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

The only difference: `"seqTime"` is returned unchanged, not `"seqTime" - '1 day'::interval` like in your function (not sure if that's even intended).

Related:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

#### Asides

There is ***no way*** to "add" columns to *any* row type variable inside plpgsql. Be it a well-known row type (`%ROWTYPE`) or an anonymous `record` - which can be re-assigned, but not have columns added once assigned.

---

> so I have declared the virtual table (is that term correct?) `rc` as:
>
> ```
> rc "Sequence"%rowtype;
> ```

[The manual clarifies:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ROWTYPES)

> A variable of a composite type is called a row variable (or row-type variable).

While reading that chapter (recommended!) also note:

> A row variable can be declared to have the same type as the rows of an
>   existing table or view, by using the ***`table_name`***`%ROWTYPE` notation; or
>   it can be declared by giving a composite type's name. (Since every
>   table has an associated composite type of the same name, it actually
>   does not matter in PostgreSQL whether you write `%ROWTYPE` or not. But
>   the form with `%ROWTYPE` is more portable.)

---

I strongly suggest to use legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers exclusively. Your CaMeL-case identifiers are a loaded foot-gun, especially when you sometimes double-quote and sometimes don't.

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: Many thanks Erwin, you have in one fell swoop clarified a number of issues for me that I was struggling to find answers to. PS the CamelCase is a carry-over for the years old database. I only started working with it less than a year ago.

Comment: Reviewing your answer @Erwin, and agree this seems most logical. Can the returned table inherit from the sequence table (similar to Pavels explanation)? This will save typing out all the sequence table column names and types. Not essential, but definitely a nice-to-have.

Comment: @witenitenz: While using `RETURNS TABLE` with `CREATE FUNCTION`, you have to provide a list of columns with existing data types. Inheritance is not applicable there. Only tables can inherit. Functions can use table types created using inheritance like any other, but cannot "inherit" a return type themselves. If you want to avoid repeating the columns of the `"Sequence"` table without complicating the function call, Pavel's solution *2.* with inheritance is the only way. But I'd rather copy the column definition list of the table *once* for `CREATE FUNCTION`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solution:

1. using composition

   ```
   create table foo1(a int, b int, c int);
   create type extended_foo AS (f foo1, a1 int, b1 int);
   create or replace function fx1()
   returns extended_foo as $$ select null::extended_foo $$
   language sql;

   postgres=# select * from fx1();
   ┌───┬────┬────┐
   │ f │ a1 │ b1 │
   ╞═══╪════╪════╡
   │   │    │    │
   └───┴────┴────┘

   postgres=# select (f).*, a1, b1 from fx1();
   ┌───┬───┬───┬────┬────┐
   │ a │ b │ c │ a1 │ b1 │
   ╞═══╪═══╪═══╪════╪════╡
   │   │   │   │    │    │
   └───┴───┴───┴────┴────┘
   ```
2. inheritance - PostgreSQL supports table inheritance (but I am not sure, if it is generally idea, but for this use case it should to work - attention: OOP in Postgres coming from old academic age and newer was completed):

   ```
   create table foo2(a1 int, b1 int) inherits(foo1);
   create or replace function fx2()
   returns foo2 as $$ select null::foo2 $$
   language sql;

   postgres=# select * from fx2();
   ┌───┬───┬───┬────┬────┐
   │ a │ b │ c │ a1 │ b1 │
   ╞═══╪═══╪═══╪════╪════╡
   │   │   │   │    │    │
   └───┴───┴───┴────┴────┘
   ```