# PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries from different database

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have found this very interesting article: [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)
from [Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter) which describes how to return all columns of various tables with only one function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_of(_table_name anyelement, _where_part text)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
      'SELECT * FROM ' || pg_typeof(_table_name)::text || ' WHERE ' || _where_part;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM data_of(NULL::tablename,'1=1 LIMIT 1');
```

This works pretty well. I need a very similar solution but for getting data from a table on a **different database via dblink**. That means the call `NULL::tablename` will fail since the table does not exists on the database where the call is made. I wonder how to make this work. Any try to connect inside of the function via dblink to a different database failed to get the result of NULL::tablename. It seems the polymorph function needs a polymorph parameter which creates the return type of the function implicit.

I would appreciate very much if anybody could help me.

Thanks a lot

Kind regards
Brian

Comment: Use a foreign table instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not the admin of the database and I think creating foreign tables for all external tables on other servers may not the smartest solution in the eyes of the responsible people, even if this may be the best way to go. Dblink instead is a well-known tool which is used very often. So maybe it is possible to get the result of **NULL::tablename** from a different database in any other way than using a foreign table?

Comment: Sure a remote select of `pg_typeof(NULL::tablename)`.

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure If I understand what you mean. This local call does not work: `SELECT * FROM data_of(pg_typeof(NULL::tablename), 17);`

Comment: Right, that's why you'll have to do it via dblink. What is `data_of`? Never heard of it.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Just to be clear. I have a polymorph function “date_of” which needs to be called with a polymorph parameter which defines the return type of the function in the same moment if the function is called. This means you can do a `select * from date_of(NULL::tablename, where_part)` and get the result of any table in the current database without knowing anything about the columns. The polymorph parameter `NULL::tablename` defines automatically how the result of the table looks like. This works pretty well BUT only on the same database.

Comment: If I would modify the part `pg_typeof(_table_name)::text` inside in the function by using dblink, it would not work since the call is still same: `select * from date_of(NULL::tablename, where_part)`. I have modified the first posting to make the request a bit more clear. :-)

Comment: Obviously you'd have to define your function on the remote DB so that it can be called via dblink.

Comment: I just added a new answer with more details. Maybe you can take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

it seems this request is more difficult to explain than I thought it is. Here is a second try with a test setup:

**Database 1**

First we create a test table with some data on database 1:

```
CREATE TABLE db1_test
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  txt text
)
WITH (
  OIDS=TRUE
);
INSERT INTO db1_test (id, txt) VALUES(1,'one');
INSERT INTO db1_test (id, txt) VALUES(2,'two');
INSERT INTO db1_test (id, txt) VALUES(3,'three');
```

Now we create the polymorph function on database 1:

```
-- create a polymorph function with a polymorph parameter "_table_name" on database 1
-- the return type is set implicit by calling the function "data_of" with the parameter "NULL::[tablename]" and a where part
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_of(_table_name anyelement, _where_part text)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
      'SELECT * FROM ' || pg_typeof(_table_name)::text || ' WHERE ' || _where_part;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now we make test call if everything works as aspected on database 1

```
SELECT * FROM data_of(NULL::db1_test, 'id=2');
```

It works. Please notice I do NOT specify any columns of the table db1_test. Now we switch over to database 2.

**Database 2**

Here I need to make exactly the same call to **data_of** from database 1 as before and although **WITHOUT** knowing the columns of the selected table at call time. Unfortunatly this is not gonna work, the only call which works is something like that:

```
SELECT
*
FROM dblink('dbname=[database1] port=[port] user=[user] password=[password]'::text, 'SELECT * FROM data_of(NULL::db1_test, \'id=2\')'::text)
t1(id integer, txt text);
```

**Conclusion**

This call works, but as you can see, I need to specify at least once how all the columns look like from the table I want to select. I am looking for any way to bypass this and make it possible to make a call WITHOUT knowing all of the columns from the table on database 1.

**Final goal**

My final goal is to create a function in database 2 which looks like

```
SELECT * from data_of_dblink('table_name','where_part')
```

and which calls internaly data_of() on database1 to make it possible to select a table on a different database with a where part as parameter. It should work like a static view but with the possiblity to pass a where part as parameter.

I am extremly open for suggestions.

Thanks a lot

Brian

Comment: I think everything up to the first sentence makes a good answer, and I'd upvote it. You should delete the rest and ask a new question about that, ideally referring to this question. But I don't think that's avoidable - you *always* have to specify how the result looks when you are using dblink. I told you about foreign tables, didn't I?