# Arbitrary string names for Postgres columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

#### Problem definition:

- I have a Postgres table `A` holding an arbitrary amount of different columns with different types, a single serial PK and millions of rows.
  Example:

```
id | val1 | val2  | val3
---+------+-------+-----
1  | 45.2 | 52.6  | 222
2  | 5.32 | 12.34 | 193
```

- I have another table `B`, mapping table `A` column names to free text string names (unique).

```
value_name | col_name
-----------+---------
 "Value 1" | "val1"
 "Value 2" | "val2"
 "Value 3" | "val3"
```

- I want to run select queries on table `A` to retrieve data by free text names (instead of column names). A single query should return the data.

Something like this would be great:

```
SELECT id
  , alias('Value 2', 'A')
  , alias('Value 3', 'A')
from  A
```

or

```
SELECT *
from alias('Value 2', 'Value 3', 'A')
```

would return

```
id | val2  | val3
---+-------+-----
1  | 52.6  | 222
2  | 12.34 | 193
```

*(I don't mind returning `id` always without explicitly asking for it, but I do need an ability to query the arbitrary amount of columns and return their original column names)*

#### Solution flexibility

- The solution can include Postgres functions, rules, extensions, triggers - anything which does not change the basic structure of table `A`.
- The solution can suggest any structure for table `B`.
- Postgres version 11

Tnx!!

Comment: I tried checking the dynamic SQL options from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557), but haven't got any helpful solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [view](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/managing-postgresql-views/) like this:

```
CREATE VIEW A_with_col_names AS select val1 "Value 1", val2 "Value 2" ...  from A;
```

Then the view can be used like:

```
Select * from A_with_col_names where "Value 1" = 'xyz'
```

Comment: That's a very interesting approach. Yet when creating a view you cannot really create indexes (unless it's a materialized view which must be refreshed). When having millions of rows - it's a problem...... Maybe there is a way to improve it somehow?

Comment: @Miro : In a matter of fact the table A will be indexed. So there is no problem I think.

Comment: @Miro Creating an index on the underlying table is enough for such a simple view.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a solution. It is not perfect though.

The principle is to build a temp table dynamically, filled it after that.

So for the following test base :

```
create table test
(
    id int primary key
    , val1 float
    , val2 float
    , val3 float
);

insert into test values
(1, 45.2, 52.6, 222), (2,5.32,12.34,193);

create table test_2
(
    value_name varchar
    , col_name varchar
);

insert into test_2 values 
('Value 1', 'val1')
, ('Value 2', 'val2')
, ('Value 3', 'val3') ;
```

you can implement the following procedure :

```
create or replace procedure querier (in_params varchar[])
language plpgsql 
as $$
declare
    query varchar;
    column_names varchar;
begin
    -- you can do pretty much all you want here to build your columns
    -- for example add a column 'type' to your second table
    select 
        string_agg(col_name, ', ') into column_names
    from test_2
    where value_name in (select unnest(in_params));

    drop table if exists temp_test cascade;
    query := 'CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_test AS 
    select id, '||column_names||' 
    from test;';
    execute query;
    --raise notice '%', query;
end;
$$;
```

And finally call the procedure and select the whole temp table:

```
call querier(cast('{"Value 1", "Value 3"}' as varchar[]));
select * from temp_test;
```

Comment: Interesting! Isn't it a huge overhead to build a temp table on every query? tnx

Comment: That's another point ;) What is the volum of IO that you are expecting? How many lines are going to be in your table? And to be honest : what is the basical need to such an architecture ? (it seems a little odd to me)

Comment: I shortened the body of the procedure.

Comment: It is an interesting approach I haven't investigated, yet it still required 2 queries at the end, so I don't see what are the benefits (aside from performance drawbacks). It's more efficient just to query the real column names 1st and query the data next.

Comment: Indeed. And I do think that the approach of @Rohit is more fit to your needs in this matter :)