# Cast value to type (TEXT) using string representation of type ("TEXT")

Tags: sql, postgresql, polymorphism, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I would like to create a function that attempts to cast a group of values into a user-specified type (with a default of text). A very simple function would look like so:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cast_to(variable jsonb, key text, target_type anyelement DEFAULT 'TEXT'::regtype) RETURNS anyelement as $$
begin
    RETURN CAST(variable->>key AS target_type);
end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

I have tried the following:

1. `SELECT CAST('foo' AS 'text');`: Gives syntax error
2. `SELECT CAST('foo' AS 'text'::regtype);`: Same error as 1
3. `SELECT CAST('foo' AS pg_typeof(null::text));` says that `type pg_typeof does not exist`

The last attempt was a thought that I could pass in a variable with the target type instead of a text representation. Using the function would then look like `SELECT cast_to('text', NULL::text);`.

How to accomplish this or similar functionality?

**Edit:** As suggested in the comments, I tried to use dynamic SQL. I am not having much luck. I created a very basic case that doesn't use any variables:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit.cast_to() RETURNS text as $$
DECLARE 
_sql TEXT := 'SELECT CAST($1 AS $2)';
out TEXT;
begin
    EXECUTE _sql
    USING 'foo', 'TEXT'
    INTO out;
    return out;
end
$$
language plpgsql;
```

That however throws the error:

> ```
> syntax error at or near "$2"
> ```

Comment: I think you need to use dynamic SQL.  A column in a result set needs to have a type that is determined at compile type.

Comment: I tried to move the [discussion to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203555/discussion-between-gammagames-and-klin) but it looks like the messages stayed here.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have tried that and edited my question with the (failed) result

Comment: @klin: Can be done after all. Remaining question is: should it be done?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: With polymorphic input types, the return type can be define at *call* time.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - Declaring the return type of a function at call time is similar to using casts. I see no point in replacing the hatchet with a stick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it can be done. Even without dynamic SQL. Pretty simple at the surface, too.

```
CREATE FUNCTION cast_to(_js jsonb, INOUT _target_type anyelement = NULL::text) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   SELECT _js ->> pg_typeof(_target_type)::text
   INTO   _target_type;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0dee2fa9317afe407e007cc5de99be5e)*

But this minimalistic function packs a couple of advanced / tricky details: See the last chapter here for basics:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

The final piece of the puzzle is to cast the `text` value returned by the `->>` operator to the return type. A simple SQL function is strict about that and does not accept a `text` for, say, an `integer`. (Nor for an `integer` defined by actual input to the polymorphic input parameter. The same goes for a PL/pgSQL function trying to simply `RETURN`. An explicit cast would be required.

[`CAST (expression AS type)` is not a normal function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS). Nor is the short syntax [`expression::type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS). Those are *constructs* or *syntax elements*. You may have noticed that the type name is placed without single quotes, i.e.: as *identifier*. (**Or** you have missed that detail, which is the cause for the first 3 syntax errors you report.) And identifiers cannot be parameterized in SQL. That would require dynamic SQL.

**However**, we can ***assign*** the `text` result of the expression to a (necessarily typed) variable or parameter to effortlessly achieve the same. The `INTO` clause will achieve that. For convenience, I assign to the `INOUT` parameter `_target_type` directly. So `_target_type` serves several purposes:

1. Defines the polymorphic return type.
2. Defines the key name for use with the JSON ->> operator. That name is carried by the *type* of `_target_type` and I extract it with `pg_typeof()` - which actually returns `regtype`, so we need to cast *that* to text explicitly.
   **Note** that always results in the Postgres standard type name, e.g: 'integer', not 'int' nor 'int4'. If your key names differ from default Postgres type names, you'll have to pass an additional parameter like you had in your original design!
3. Serves as `OUT` parameter (so we do not need to `DECLARE` a variable) that can be assigned to.
4. Has a `DEFAULT` value attached to it: `= NULL::text`, so the second parameter can be omitted to just return `text`.
   You tried that in your original, but <strike>`DEFAULT 'TEXT'::regtype`</strike> was off target.

You may want to split some of these purposes to multiple parameters / variables.

So it can be done.
**Question** is: why do you want to do it? Often, there is a faster and less tricky solution around the corner - even if more verbose.

Comment: "Those are constructs or syntax elements." That's what I thought, and it made sense why I couldn't easily parameterize them. This answer is magic and you've really earned your "About me" summary.

Comment: As to why, I wanted to [make a function](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343239/postgis-doesnt-automatically-convert-wkb-to-geojson) that would, when given a row cast into JSON, attempt to convert any geometry (automatically cast to GeoJSON as of PostGIS 3.0) into the return type the user wanted. 
Since then, I decided to make a `cast_as_text` and if I needed other types I would just make more functions, so this question turned into more of a "can I" because I realized how I was making it a bit more complicated than needed.