# Dynamically cast type of array elements to match some expression type in PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, types, dynamic-sql

I want to use [`array_position`](https://pgpedia.info/a/array_position.html) function in PostgreSQL (which takes array of some type and expression or value of the same type) for constructing query that returns rows in some arbitrary order (additional context: I want to enhance [Ruby on Rails `in_order_of` feature](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/42061) which is currently implemented via unreadable `CASE` statement):

```sql
SELECT id, title, type
FROM posts
ORDER BY
  array_position(ARRAY['SuperSpecial','Special','Ordinary']::varchar[], type),
  published_at DESC;
```

The problem here is that requirement to do explicit type casting from type inferred by PostgreSQL from array literal (`ARRAY['doh']` is `text[]`) to type of expression (`type` is `varchar` here). While `varchar` and `text` are coercible to each other, PostgreSQL requires explicit type cast, otherwise if omit it (like in `array_position(ARRAY['doh'], type)`) PostgreSQL will throw error (see [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/212217/61198) for details):

```
ERROR: function array_position(text[], character varying) does not exist                                                   
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

While it is not a problem to specify explicit type cast in some static queries, it is problem in autogenerated queries when type of expression is unknown beforehand: `array_position(ARRAY[1,2,3], id * 2)` (what type has `id * 2`?)

I thought that [`pg_typeof()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-info.html#id-1.5.8.32.19.2.2.25.1.1.1) could help me, but it seems that it can't be used neither in `::` operator nor in `CAST` operator (I've seen information that both forms aren't function forms, but syntax constructs, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59164197/cast-value-to-type-text-using-string-representation-of-type-text) for details):

```sql
SELECT id, title, type
FROM posts
ORDER BY array_position(CAST(ARRAY['SpecialPost','Post','Whatever'] AS pg_typeof(type)), type), id;
```

```
ERROR:  type "pg_typeof" does not exist
LINE 1: ...on(CAST(ARRAY['SpecialPost','Post','Whatever'] AS pg_typeof(...
```

**Question:

How to do dynamic typecast to expression type (say, to type of `"posts"."id" * 2`) in the same SQL query?**

I would prefer to avoid extra roundtrip to database server (like executing `SELECT pg_typeof("id" * 2) FROM "posts" LIMIT 1` and then using its result in generating of a new query) or writing some custom functions. Is it possible?

Comment: While the data type of `type` (which should be called "element") in your example is unknown, the data type of the array is well-known when writing the query, right? So cast `type` to the element type of the array? BTW, [this referenced answer of mine](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/212217/3684) deals with `anyarray`, which makes things harder.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, thank you! I wonder how many edge cases may hide here, if user specified strings in the array, when expression in the second argument evaluates to uuids, points, some postgis types or whatever. How reliably it will work if cast everything to strings always for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Better query

> I want to enhance Ruby on Rails `in_order_of` feature which is currently implemented via unreadable `CASE` statement:

For starters, neither the awkward `CASE` construct nor `array_position()` are ideal solutions.

> ```
> SELECT id, title, type
> FROM posts
> ORDER BY
>   array_position(ARRAY['SuperSpecial','Special','Ordinary']::varchar[], type),
>   published_at DESC;
> ```

There is a superior solution in Postgres:

```sql
SELECT id, title, type
FROM   posts
LEFT   JOIN unnest(ARRAY['SuperSpecial','Special','Ordinary']::varchar[]) WITH ORDINALITY o(type, ord) USING (type)
ORDER  BY o.ord, published_at DESC;
```

This avoids calling the function `array_position()` for every row and is cheaper.
Equivalent short syntax with array literal and implicit column name:

```sql
SELECT id, title, type
FROM   posts
LEFT   JOIN unnest('{SuperSpecial,Special,Ordinary}'::varchar[]) WITH ORDINALITY type USING (type)
ORDER  BY ordinality, published_at DESC;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c51c207a6a068c1ebabaaaaa423bf2c0)*

Added "benefit": it *works* with type-mismatch in Postgres 13 - as long as array type and column type are *compatible*.

The only **possible caveat** I can think of: If the passed array has duplicate elements, joined rows are duplicated accordingly. That wouldn't happen with `array_position()`. But duplicates would be nonsense for the expressed purpose in any case. Make sure to pass unique array elements.

See:

- [ORDER BY the IN value list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/order-by-the-in-value-list/35456954#35456954)
- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

#### Improved functionality in Postgres 14

The error you report is going away with Postgres 14:

> ```
> ERROR: function array_position(text[], character varying) does not exist                                                   
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

Quoting the [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/release-14.html#id-1.11.6.5.5.8):

> - Allow some array functions to operate on a mix of compatible data
>   types (Tom Lane)
>
>   The functions `array_append()`, `array_prepend()`, `array_cat()`,
>   `array_position()`, `array_positions()`, `array_remove()`,
>   `array_replace()`, and `width_bucket()` now take `anycompatiblearray`
>   instead of `anyarray` arguments. This makes them less fussy about
>   exact matches of argument types.

And [the manual on `anycompatiblearray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC-TABLE):

> Indicates that a function accepts any array data type, with automatic promotion of multiple arguments to a common data type

So, while this raises the above error msg in Postgres 13:

```
SELECT array_position(ARRAY['a','b','c']::text[], 'd'::varchar);
```

.. the same just works in Postgres 14.

(Your query and error msg show flipped positions for `text` and `varchar`, but all the same.)

To be clear, calls with *compatible* types now just work, *incompatible* types still raise an exception:

```
SELECT array_position('{1,2,3}'::text[], 3);
```

(The numeric literal `3` defaults to type `integer`, which is incompatible with `text`.)

#### Answer to actual question

.. which may be irrelevant by now. But as proof of concept:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION posts_order_by(_order anyarray)
 RETURNS SETOF posts
 LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format (
   $$
   SELECT p.*
   FROM   posts p
   LEFT   JOIN unnest($1) WITH ORDINALITY o(type, ord) ON (o.type::%s = p.type)
   ORDER  BY o.ord, published_at DESC
   $$
  , (SELECT atttypid::regtype
     FROM   pg_attribute
     WHERE  attrelid = 'posts'::regclass
     AND    attname = 'type')
   )
   USING _order;
END
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c51c207a6a068c1ebabaaaaa423bf2c0)*

Doesn't make a whole lot of sense, as the type of `posts.id` should be well-known at the time of writing the function, but there may be special cases ...

Now both of these calls work:

```
SELECT * FROM posts_order_by('{SuperSpecial,Special,Ordinary}'::varchar[]);    
SELECT * FROM posts_order_by('{1,2,3}'::int[]);
```

Though the second typically doesn't make sense.

Related, with links to more:

- [Executing queries dynamically in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616126/executing-queries-dynamically-in-pl-pgsql/29617481#29617481)

Comment: `LEFT JOIN unnest(…) WITH ORDINALITY` works like a charm, thank you!
I wonder is there any caveats in real-world queries due to unexpected join added, but it really solves the problem with type mismatch for older versions of PostgreSQL, especially for expressions (which now can be handled in join condition):
```SELECT posts.* FROM posts LEFT JOIN unnest(ARRAY[6, 4, 2]) WITH ORDINALITY in_order_of(value, position) ON (posts.id * 2) = in_order_of.value ORDER BY in_order_of.position;```
However, can't see much value in declaring functions for that.

Comment: @Envek: I added a possible caveat above. The function is just proof of concept, to answer the original question. The "better query" is the solution I suggest for the task.