# How to pass variable from PL/pgSQL function to a query select statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_of(_tbl_type anyelement, _missing_id TEXT)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('
      SELECT *
        from logs
        where json_col_a::text like '%$1%' or   -- <---- faulty
            json_col_b::text like '%$1%'        --- <----- faulty
        order by timestamp desc'
    , pg_typeof(_tbl_type))
   USING  _missing_id;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TABLE new_table AS TABLE logs WITH NO DATA;

SELECT * FROM data_of(NULL::new_table, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001');
```

Adapted from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751557/4177530), I want to pass a GUID as a text into the `SELECT` query.

I convert the `json_col_a`, `json_col_b` from `json` to `text`.

Then, I check whether the `_missing_id` text is found in both columns above.

When I run, I got an error message saying:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown % new_table
> LINE 4:   where diagnostics_context::text like '%$1%' or

What have I missed?
Thanks

Comment: What's the purpose of the "tbl_type" parameter?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I want to pass the `RETURN QUERY` to the `tbl_type` parameter. I thought the `tbl_type` could get the return value of the `Select` query. Please correct me if I am wrong.