# How to define a function returning one of multiple data types?

Tags: postgresql, function, types

I have a function with a conditional result. Based on the argument value it should either return `varchar` or `int` or `uuid` or `timestamp`.

What should the return type of that function be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is strictly typed. The simple solution is to return **one `text` field**. Every value can be cast to `text`. (You might add a second return column holding the type name as meta information.)

Alternatively, return **four typed fields** `(varchar, int, uuid, timestamp)`, and only fill one of them, depending on the result.

A [polymorphic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC) function would only be an option if you can tell the return type at call time and pass typed input accordingly.

Related:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)