# Postgres SQL - get column name as variable

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlc

I am trying to have a query that will be something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table 
WHERE $1 = $2
```

I am using sqlc to generate everything needed to execute the query so I don't have the option the use a formatted string.

I was also trying to do it this way

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table
WHERE 
    CASE 
        WHEN $1 = "name"
            THEN name
            ELSE id
    END = $2;
```

But could not find a way to make it work right

Is there any way to do something like this?

Thanks you!

Comment: *"Is there any way to do something like this?"* -- No. You cannot use parameter placeholders for identifiers like column names etc. You can use parameter placeholders ONLY for values. A column name is NOT a value. Re-think. Re-design.

Comment: There is a way you can accomplish this, but it's not something I'd recommend if there is an alternative. You can move the query into a postgres function that uses [dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751557/11810946) (see the PostgreSQL 9.1 example) and then call that from your application (the table name can be passed in as a string or determined using logic within the function).

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I will try to think of a different approach!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use a PostgreSQL function to achieve this. e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_dynamic_query(param_name text, param_value text)
RETURNS TABLE (id INT, name TEXT) AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF param_name = 'name' THEN
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE name = $1' USING param_value;
    ELSIF param_name = 'id' THEN
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = $1' USING param_value;
    ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid parameter name';
    END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Used like so

```
SELECT * FROM my_dynamic_query('name', 'John');
```