# "RETURNS TABLE (col record)" in a PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function in PL/pgSQL that accepts a `record` type parameter, and returns 1 record type as well:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.f_obtem_record_auth(record);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_obtem_record_auth(
    rec RECORD 
    -- trabalhar com apenas um aparametro do tipo record 
    -- return record 
)
RETURNS TABLE(
    /*auth TEXT
    , code INTEGER */
    auth RECORD
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$ 
DECLARE 
    vrecordauth RECORD;
BEGIN
    -- LOGIN IPP
    -- TRATAR ERROS, CODIGOS <> 200 OU '' PARA TODAS AS BANDEIRAS 
    IF (rec.codigo_bandeira = '00001') THEN 
        WITH  sub_primeira_req AS (
      -- my code
        ), sub_segunda_req AS (
      -- my code        
        ), sub_terceira_req AS ( 
          -- my code 
        ), sub_quarta_req AS ( 
            SELECT
            -- my code
        )
        SELECT 
            jtr."AuthProxyJWT" auth,
            sub.code
        INTO vrecordauth
        FROM sub_quarta_req sub
        , JSONB_TO_RECORD(sub.cookies) AS jtr (
            "AuthProxyJWT" TEXT
        );
          auth := vrecordauth;
        RETURN NEXT;
    -- AUTENTICAÇÃO IPP PEGAR NO NOT PAD++
    
    ELSE 
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Código bandeira: [%] desconhecido. Entre em contato com o desenvolvedor', PCodigoEmpresa;
    END IF;
END;
$function$;
```

I want it to accept a `record` parameter, and naturally I will be able to access nested fields. Example:

```
rec.user
rec.password
```

This part is well resolved and works, the part that doesn't seem to work is this:

```sql
RETURNS TABLE(
    /*auth TEXT
    , code INTEGER */
    auth RECORD
)
```

So I made a second function to test the first:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.f_testa_login();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_testa_login()
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE 
    rec             RECORD;
    VRecordAuth     RECORD; 
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        CAST('' AS TEXT) usuario
        , CAST('' AS TEXT) senha  
        , CAST('' AS TEXT) auth
        , CAST('' AS TEXT) cookies
        , CAST('' AS TEXT) ltpatoken
        , CAST('' AS TEXT) subjsession
        , CAST('' AS TEXT) javax
        , CAST('' AS TEXT) codigo_empresa
        , CAST('' AS TEXT) codigo_fornecedor
        , CAST('' AS TEXT) codigo_produto
    INTO  VRecordAuth;
    
    FOR rec IN 
        SELECT
             -- my code
        FROM    bandeira b 
            -- my code
        WHERE   e.registro_ativo 
        AND fpe.registro_ativo 
        AND pe.registro_ativo 
        AND p.registro_ativo 
        GROUP BY 
            -- my group by 
        ORDER BY 
            -- my order by 
    LOOP 
        IF (rec.nome_bandeira = 'SHELL') THEN 
            IF (VRecordAuth.usuario != rec.usuario OR VRecordAuth.senha != rec.senha OR VRecordAuth.auth = '') THEN 
                SELECT 
                    CAST(rec.usuario AS TEXT) 
                    , CAST(rec.senha AS TEXT)  
                    , auth 
                INTO VRecordAuth
                FROM f_obtem_record_auth(rec)
                AS auth_record(auth RECORD);
                RAISE NOTICE 'Usuario: %', auth_record;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$function$
; 
SELECT * FROM f_testa_login()
```

I tried sending `record` type parameters (stored in var `rec`) and I sent this rec as a parameter in my function `f_obtem_record_auth()`
and I inserted the result into a variable (`VRecordAuth`) of type `record` too, to access the fields of this result later, and that's where the problem lies, when I print `VRecordAuth` I get the error:

> ```
> ERROR: record "auth" is not assigned yet
> Detalhe: The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.  
> Onde: PL/pgSQL function f_obtem_record_auth(record) line 76 at RETURN NEXT  
> SQL statement "SELECT 
>                   CAST(rec.usuario AS TEXT) 
>                   , CAST(rec.senha AS TEXT)  
>                   , auth 
>                                              FROM f_obtem_record_auth(rec)
>               AS auth_record(auth RECORD)"
> PL/pgSQL function f_testa_login() line 94 at SQL statement
> ```

But when I change the return from the `f_obtem_recor_auth()` function to:

```sql
RETURNS TABLE(
    auth TEXT
    , code INTEGER
)
```

everything works as expected and in my test function I can access the returns from the `f_obtem_record_auth()` function.

Why is this happening?
Why do I get the error mentioned above?
Why can't I just use a table return with a record type containing several fields?

I'm a beginner in programming so be patient with me.

Comment: Please try and come up with a short, simple test case that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Q: *Why is this happening? Why do I get the error mentioned above? Why can't I just use a table return with a record type containing several fields?*

Note that `record` is not a type, but a [pseudo-type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-pseudo.html).

You may still use it to return results from a function, but not in combination with `TABLE`. The declaration is `RETURNS SETOF record`

Here's a very simple example

```
CREATE FUNCTION pltest() RETURNS SETOF record
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE r record;
BEGIN
  select 'v1' AS col1, 'v2' AS col2 into r;
  return next r;
END
$function$
;
```

When calling this function from an SQL query, it is necessary to fully specify a "column definition list" in the query, so that the query planner knows the count and types of the columns from these records.

Example:

```
select * from pltest() as x(a text, b text);

 a  | b  
----+----
 v1 | v2
```

See for more:

- [Record Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS) in the manual
- [Polymorphic SQL Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-POLYMORPHIC-FUNCTIONS) in the manual
- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557) on this site for more insights into the limits of polymorphism with plpgsql.

Comment: *"... but not in combination with `TABLE`."* Can be done, though: https://dbfiddle.uk/ty8WRIOF. While being at it, I think I ran into a PL/pgSQL bug ...

Answer (score 0):

#### Immediate fix

The **immediate problem** that causes the error is buried in your function `f_obtem_record_auth()` here:

```
SELECT 
    jtr."AuthProxyJWT" auth,
    sub.code
INTO vrecordauth
...
auth := vrecordauth;
RETURN NEXT;
```

Adding another `ROW` wrapper makes it work:

```
SELECT ROW (jtr."AuthProxyJWT", sub.code)
INTO vrecordauth
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5nHWCc3Y)

Doesn't make it a good idea though. Much too convoluted. There are simpler solutions ...

Also, I think we found a bug:

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ty8WRIOF)

#### Basics

**`record`** is not an actual [data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html). [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS)

> Note that `RECORD` is not a true data type, only a placeholder. One should also realize that when a PL/pgSQL function is declared
> to return type `record`, this is not quite the same concept as a
> record variable, even though such a function might use a record
> variable to hold its result. In both cases the actual row structure is
> unknown when the function is written, but for a function returning
> `record` the actual structure is determined when the calling query is
> parsed, whereas a record variable can change its row structure
> on-the-fly.

You assume:

> I want it to accept a record parameter, and naturally I will be able to access nested fields.

No. You must pass a well-known row type (= composite type) containing all the fields that are hard-coded in the function body. Or you must cast the anonymous record to such a well-known row type, before you can access its fields.

Cases where such a construct makes sense are few and far between. I have never had such a case. But it's possible.