# How to change column names returned from a function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

How to change column names returned from below function?

Executing:

```
select * from get_parameterbased_return_Table('condition2');
```

Column names should change to `(col3 text, col4 text)`

**Sample table and function:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.parameterbased_return_table (
    col1 text NULL,
    col2 text NULL,
    col3 int4 NULL,
    col4 int4 NULL
);


INSERT INTO public.parameterbased_return_table (col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES
  ('A', 'B', 11, 22)
, ('dfdf', 'dfe', 14, 545)
;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_parameterbased_return_Table(condition TEXT)
RETURNS TABLE (col1 text, col2 text) AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF condition = 'condition1' THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT t.col1::text, t.col2::text FROM parameterbased_return_Table t;
    ELSIF condition = 'condition2' THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT t.col3::text, t.col4::text FROM parameterbased_return_Table t;
    ELSE
        -- Handle other conditions or return an empty result set
        RETURN QUERY SELECT NULL::record;
    END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Just the names or the data types, too? (Given that `col3` & `col4` are `integer`)?

Comment: the names only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres (like SQL) is strictly typed. Functions cannot change their return type on the fly - including number, names and types of columns for a function returning a row type.

There are a limited workarounds, but you have to pass the required information with the function call one or the other way.

#### [Polymorphic function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC) to change the whole return type

Here, the trick is to pass the actual return type to the function. See:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Only makes sense for exotic use cases.
That said, here is how you pull off such a stunt:

```sql
-- create desired return types
CREATE TYPE public.result1 AS (col1 text, col2 text);
CREATE TYPE public.result2 AS (col2 int, col3 int);

-- create polymorphis function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_parameterbased_return_table1(_return_type anyelement)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   CASE pg_typeof(_return_type)
   WHEN 'public.result1'::regtype THEN
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT t.col1, t.col2
      FROM   parameterbased_return_table t;
   WHEN 'public.result2'::regtype THEN
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT t.col3, t.col4  -- returning actual int values
      FROM   parameterbased_return_table t;
   ELSE
      -- Handle other conditions or return an empty result set
      -- just don't return anything (simpler)
   END CASE;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM public.get_parameterbased_return_table1(null::public.result1);
```

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| dfdf | dfe |

```
SELECT * FROM public.get_parameterbased_return_table1(null::public.result2);
```

| col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 22 |
| 14 | 545 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bbHKSai0)

This also returns original data types. You can really return *anything* here.

#### Plain column aliases

Again, you have to provide the information in the call. Keeping your original function, you can use column aliases in the call:

```
SELECT * FROM public.get_parameterbased_return_table('condition2') AS t(col3, col4);
```

| col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 22 |
| 14 | 545 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3rsoT7j5)